# Stripe Connect - Cloning External Account (Bank Account) as Source for New Customer

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Our software is switching up the way we bill our platform users, and we'd like to find the most efficient way to have a 'Customer' created for each of our Connect accounts without having them re-enter their bank account information.

Is it possible to clone the external bank account on a Connect account and use it as a default source on a new Customer?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to clone a bank account token from an already attached external account. You have to collect their bank account details again to attach to a Customer object.

A workaround you can do for new Connect accounts is:

1/ Create a bank account token (representing the Connect account's external account) on the Platform account. Attach that token to a Customer on the Platform (this Customer represents the Connect account) and verify the bank account (covered in this guide here: https://stripe.com/docs/ach-deprecated).

You solved for:

> have a 'Customer' created for each of our Connect accounts

2/ You clone that bank account (ba_123) as a token on the Connect account: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/cloning-customers-across-accounts#creating-tokens

and then you attach this token as the Connect account's external account.